# How can I figure out how much my site is worth?

Tags: web-hosting

I run an entertainment website that gets about 4.5-4.75 million pageviews a month and 30k+ visitors daily and I have been thinking about selling it. The website brings in $6,000-$9,000 a month but I have no idea how to evaluate or how to prepare information for someone that would be willing to buy the website.

Are there any guidelines that I should follow? How much do websites sell for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Websites can easily sell for two times yearly earnings.  Based on the earnings you report here, you could sell your site for around $200K without much hassle.

If you have a good business model, a long history of revenue, good relations with Google (no penalty history, no spammy tactics that are likely to get you penalized), and constantly increasing revenues, then your website could be worth up to ten times yearly earnings.  So up to $1M in your case.  Selling your website for that much takes a lot more work and luck on your part to find the interested buyer.

Interested buyers are going to want to see at least the following data:

- Earnings history
- Expense history (hosting, marketing, and other costs)
- How much time/effort it takes to keep the site running
- Analytics

  - Traffic history
  - Traffic sources
  - Number of registered users
- Which SEO firms you have hired, or what SEO you have done on your own
- What technologies you use, and what their licenses are
- List of competitors
- List of anything that could be risky for your business

Comment: Trend would also have a factor on this if its declining or increasing.

Comment: Number of registered users?

Comment: Very nice to have some pointers, thank you. What would you say would be within the scope of "risky for your business"? Would trends be one of of these factors? I mean, you still want to sell your site without scaring them off somehow, right?

Comment: You certainly don't want to scare them off by overstating risks, but it would be unethical to withhold information from them.